# Python replace empty array with zero

Tags: python, pandas

What is the easiest way to replace an empty array with zeros?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
               'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
               'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [5, 8, 9, 10],
               'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
               'sale': [60, 70, 95,85]})



df1.loc[(df1['year']==2012) ,'sale'].values+ df2.loc[(df2['year']==2020) ,'sale'].values

results is 
array([], dtype=int64)
```

I want to either pass on empty array or replace it with zeros.

Comment: if you describe exactly what you are trying to accomplish I'll be there is a better approach altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am working with big data .  I have to sum several data frames based on some conditions. But some of the conditions result in empty array for some dataframes and therefore the sum would also be empty.  In the example above , df1.loc[(df1['year']==2012) ,'sale'].values has value but  df2.loc[(df2['year']==2020) ,'sale'].values is empty and therefore the sum of those would be empty too. I want to either pass on empty array or replace it with zeros or NaN . The foo function from the user d.b solve the problem !

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(arr):
    if arr.size == 0:
        return np.empty(1)
    else:
        return arr

foo(df1.loc[(df1['year']==2012) ,'sale'].values) + foo(df2.loc[(df2['year']==2020) ,'sale'].values)
# array([55.])
```

Comment: Thank you. your help solved my problem.